# react native pod install fails with firebase

Tags: ios, react-native, cocoapods

When Trying to run pod install for react native project , I got the following error

```
[!] Error installing Firebase

――― MARKDOWN TEMPLATE ―――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――

### Command
```

C:/Ruby30-x64/bin/pod install

```
### Report

* What did you do?

* What did you expect to happen?

* What happened instead?


### Stack
```

CocoaPods : 1.10.1
Ruby : ruby 3.0.1p64 (2021-04-05 revision 0fb782ee38) [x64-mingw32]
RubyGems : 3.2.15
Host : Unable to find an executable (No such file or directory - sw_vers)  ()
Xcode : -version) ()
Git : git version 2.23.0.windows.1
Ruby lib dir : C:/Ruby30-x64/lib
Repositories : cocoapods - git - https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git @ f587e47de45e30c653e2d258a78c364cbec08bb6

```
### Plugins
```

cocoapods-deintegrate : 1.0.4
cocoapods-plugins     : 1.0.0
cocoapods-search      : 1.0.0
cocoapods-trunk       : 1.5.0
cocoapods-try         : 1.2.0

````
### Podfile

```ruby
require_relative '../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods'
require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'

platform :ios, '11.0'
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

target 'BankSms' do
  config = use_native_modules!

  use_react_native!(
    :path => config[:reactNativePath],
    # to enable hermes on iOS, change `false` to `true` and then install pods
    :hermes_enabled => false
  )

  target 'BankSmsTests' do
    inherit! :complete
    # Pods for testing
  end

  # Enables Flipper.
  #
  # Note that if you have use_frameworks! enabled, Flipper will not work and
  # you should disable the next line.
  use_flipper!()

  post_install do |installer|
    react_native_post_install(installer)
  end
end
````

#### Error

```
Errno::ENOENT - No such file or directory @ dir_s_mkdir - /Caches/CocoaPods/Pods/Release/Firebase/7.11.0-c121f/FirebaseInAppMessaging/Tests/Integration/FunctionalTestApp/ExternalAppExample/fiam-external-ios-testing-app/fiam-external-ios-testing-app/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset
```

How to bypass that error ??

Answer (score 1):

There can be multiple reason for this.

There is one solution which always worked for me is

```
sudo pod install --allow-root
```

Thank you!